# Notify for Quantity Below in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, stock, cataloginventory, notification

I have a requirements to notify the admin through email when a product quantity goes below 5 in Magento 2.0.7.

I have found that there is option on the admin:

**System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options section**

But setting the **Notify for Quantity Below** to 5 is not sending any emails to admin when an order is placed.

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: You check the log exception? There are any error?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I have checked the log exception. There is just 2 log files: debug and system. There is no logs.

Comment: Have you able to receive email of low stock notification

Comment: have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no low-stock notification by email in Magento 2. You can be notified by RSS or by accessing Reports -> Products -> Low Stock in admin menu.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16868#issuecomment-407058403

Answer (score 0):

Download below extension from github and install in you website. It's working fine.

https://github.com/bharat2762/magento2-admin-low-stock-notification