# Magento 2: Low Stock Notification Email to Admin

Tags: magento2, email, stock, inventory, magento-2.1.3

We have below settings

**Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options**

```
Notify for Quantity Below -> 1
```

Admin is not getting email fo Low Stock Products.

[Notify for Quantity Below in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130065/notify-for-quantity-below-in-magento-2)

I want to send email if quantity is below X or how can we send Low Stock Report via Email Daily (CronJob)

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/out-of-stock-notification-settings-magento-2.html Check this one. It will help.

Answer (score 4):

In magento direct email not sending to the admin. Magento show low stock report at Reports > Product > Low stock

For Magento 2.2.x Admin Low Stock Notification email Free extension available in github https://github.com/bharat2762/magento2-admin-low-stock-notification

For Magento 2.3.x Admin Low Stock Notification email Free extension available in github https://github.com/bharat2762/magento2.3.x-admin-low-stock-notification

heck this one. It will help.

Comment: it works for magento 2.3 and not for 2.2.6

Comment: This is not working for 2.2.x. what is your requirement for Low stock email?

Comment: if stock is 0 then have to mail to suppliers , as per the link provided its perfect i think so but it fails when i try to apply it on 2.2.6

Comment: I have updated answer. Here is an extension for 2.2.x -https://github.com/bharat2762/magento2-admin-low-stock-notification

Comment: thx. just one more question, will it get executed via cron or when customer purchases last item of that stock after its successfully placed

Comment: It will execute when customer place order. You can create issue in git for advance feature.

Comment: I am newbie in magento, what i meant to say do i have to run it via cron or will it run automatically when customer place order and its status is changed to successful and thx for your code.

Comment: It works like a charm but I also  need one of the additional features in the above extension I also need that send a notification mail for "Out of Stock" Products too like as "Low stock admin notification". can you please suggest me with any idea @Bharat Patel

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not sending email to anyone, product inventory lower then "Notify for quantity below" will be included in the " low inventory alerts RSS feed" and it can be seen in the RSS feed .

Comment: From where to get low inventory alerts RSS feed?

Comment: you need to go store> configuration > catalog > RSS feeds and open it, by default it is closed

Comment: Already enabled. Now in frontend i'm not able to see for Subscribe to this RSS Feed

Comment: frontend link is : /rss/index/index
backend link i am still finding